# Whats the proper way of maintaining code for mapping of server side thrown id' s on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, titanium-mobile

i am developing a mobile app in titanium with javascript for iPad. The data on client is requested from a REST based service. The result json gives different types of status ids which currently i am maintaining by mapping them to an array on client-side to show them on frontend which is making lot of garbage in my files. I was thinking of maintain these arrays separately by making them into enums in a separate js file and then require them..What approach should be taken for the same?

For e.g.: When  json sends ids as 0 so i maintain an array like var status = ['Approved-Procurable', 'Submitted to Partner', 'Full Receipt'] on client side file and show them Approved Procurable as the status.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a solution where this data is provided by your rest api. If this is not possible you should create a separate JS file which contains all the request logic - maybe called RequestProvider.

There you can place all your request calls and prepare their answers. In your "Controllers" you simply call `RequestProvider.doRequest(params, callbackSuccess, callbackError)`.

```
function RequestProvider(){}

RequestProvider.prototype.doRequest = function(params, success, error, scope) {
 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
         // prepare & modify answer
         var answer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         //modify array
         var modifiedAnswer = // replace parts in original answer;
         success.call(scope || this, modifiedAnswer);
     },
     // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug(e.error);
         error.call(scope || this, errormessage);
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
   });
   // Prepare the connection.
   client.open("GET", url);
   // Send the request.
   client.send(); 
 }
 RequestProvider = new RequestProvider();
 module.exports = RequestProvider;
```

Main Concept is to do all request logic only once!

Comment: @ mr.VVoo thanks but it seems you did not get the question..It wasnt about sending the request. I was talking about the data that was already recieved in the JSON response.

Comment: yes i know and in `onload` you can modify this answer. and if you have this code in its own *.js you don't need to adjust its. The important function is `onload: function (e)`.

Comment: i updated the code a bit. so you need to maintain your array only once in this request provider instead of many times at each part in your code.